# passing a variable from a gridview to another page, and inserting it to a header

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am currently working with a gridviews in asp.net(vb).  I have it where I am able to pass information from `gridview1` to `gridview2` on the next page.  However, what I need to do now is pass a variable from a column in `gridview2` to the header of that page.

ei. in `Gridview2` we have a column and all results are the same, the column header is *StoreName* and all the data for column is *Sears*

I know how to make the entire column invisible, but at the top of the page I need a sentence that looks like this:

Store Information for *Sears*

I am having trouble with what the code would look like for that line, all the thing I have tried have resulting in using a variable before it is declared. 
I need this line to be dynamic as the results will not always be for Sears. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: People will be more inclined to help you if you accept their answers more often.

Comment: Perhaps post some code about how you're passing the current information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think there are probably much better ways to accomplish what you're trying to do, but to answer your question, you can retrieve values from your GridView like this:

```
string storeName = yourGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].Text;
```

Then I suppose you could do something like this:

```
lblYourLabel.Text = "Store Information for " + storeName;
```

I don't think it's a great idea to pull this information directly from your grid based on an index though. If those columns get rearranged your code no longer works. Instead pull the store name from the data that you are using to populate the grid.

Comment: thanks for the response friend, I think your method is the right path, however when I place the code it gives me "End of statement expected" error.... any thoughts? Also, will this method work if the column is set to invisible?

Comment: No, you can't use that method to get the values of cells in hidden columns, but you can work around that problem. One way is to set the column to visible = true, databind, then set the column to visible = false.

Comment: As far as the code not working, you'll have to change the variable names to match your definitions, and replace "rowIndex" and "cellIndex" with the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a button you can pass a value through the CommandArguement

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbSelectStore" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" Text="<%# Bind("StoreName") %>" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("StoreID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Alternately you can just do it as a HyperLink and pass the value in the query string.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Store" >
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StopeName") %>' NavigateUrl='~/StoreDetails.aspx?Store=<%# Bind("StoreID") %>'>HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```